# Django queryset filter GT, LT, GTE, LTE returns full object list

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to filter objects in my database using `.filter(field__lte = parameter)` however it just returns ALL objects and does not filter any out. I have even set the parameter to well above any value that is stored in the database and all objects are still returned.

```
>> all_objects = Ranked.objects.all()
>> filtered = all_objects.filter(score__lte = 100) #The max possible score is 100
>> len(filtered)
87 #Every object in the db
```

The field in the database that I am querying against is an `IntegerField`.

Am I doing something wrong here? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Perhaps all objects score is <= 100. Are you sure there are objects whose score is > 100?

Comment: Try doing `score__lte=10` and see if you get the same result. It looks fine to me -  max is 100, and get me everything less than or equal to 100

Comment: Django ORM interprets the condition you supply to ``filter`` not as _"filter these away"_, but rather as _"let these go through"_.

Answer (score 18):

As you said max possible score is `100` so it will always return all objects because `lte` means return all objects whose score is either less than or equal to `100`. You might need `lt` lookup which means just return those objects whose score is less than `100`:

```
filtered = all_objects.filter(score__lt=100)
```

Answer (score 10):

You are saying that `The max possible score is 100`. By using `score__lte=100`, you are filtering all objects with `score` **less than or equal to** 100 - which is every object in the table by your own  definition.